# Arraylist take the last object from url. and replace an append(";") by a(" ") in the last object, Java

Tags: java

good afternoon, I would need help with the following method where I have a list of rooms, for example, and it is to print a URL with the data. only that the last data of the list would need to remove the .append(";") which would be the separator and replace it with (" ") or remove the ; . Only in the cases of the last object (room),

I investigated but I would not know what is best if the size or the lastIndexOf

example

```
rooms.get(rooms.size()-1); -->option 1
rooms.lastIndexOf(room); --> option 2
```

the url comes as follows,
https://hotel.google.net/hotels/ytd.proba.miami,2/MIA/XXXXX-XXXXX/1DR;1DR;?token=Ws2QmzjsxDFC7jeN&

I would only need the last 1DR to not have the ; just the last. If I'm missing any more information, tell me. Thanks a lot

```
   private String getFormattedRooms(List<HotelRoom> rooms) {
        StringBuilder formattedRooms = new StringBuilder();
        for (HotelRoom room : rooms) { 
    
formattedRooms.append("1").append(getSupplierRoomType(room)).append(getChildrenAges(room)).append(";");
        }
        return formattedRooms.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're actually building is a series of strings joined by `';'`, so why not build each string and then join them?

With streams, for example:

```
rooms.stream()
     .map(room -> "1" + getSupplierRoomType(room) + getChildrenAges(room))
     .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

Without streams:

```
private String getFormattedRooms(List<HotelRoom> rooms) {
    List<String> roomStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (HotelRoom room : rooms) { 
        roomStrings.add("1" + getSupplierRoomType(room) + getChildrenAges(room));
    }
    return String.join(";", roomStrings);
}
```